# How to create Flux from http requests

Tags: java, spring-mvc, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'd like to create a Flux from multiple incoming http requests to a spring-mvc rest method, or a spring-webflux method.
I.e., any new method call, its body will be added to the Flux.
The request can come from any client, and not necessarily a WebClient.

Comment: You cannot. Multiple requests execute on different threads and you cannot join them in a single flux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achive it with `Flux.create` method

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class EchoController
{
    private final Consumer<String> requestConsumer; // consumer to send signal to the flux

    public EchoController()
    {
        List<Consumer<String>> requestConsumerHolder = new ArrayList<>(); // temporary holder

        Flux<String> stringFlux = Flux.create(fluxSink ->
            requestConsumerHolder.add(fluxSink::next)); // when consumer accepts string it calls FluxSink.next

        stringFlux
            .doOnNext(System.out::println) // print string on next
            .subscribe();

        requestConsumer = requestConsumerHolder.get(0);
    }

    @PostMapping("/echo")
    public Mono<String> echo(@RequestBody Mono<String> request)
    {
        return request.doOnNext(requestConsumer); // send string to the flux on next
    }
}
```